# Switched-Capacitor Bank Question

Tags: capacitor

Consider the following setup:

[image: tKi4x.png]

Capacitors C1, C2, C3, C4 where C1 = C2 = 2C and C3 = C4 = C. **All the capacitors in the bank have their top/positive plate connected together at the common central node**. The bottom plate of C1 and C3 is connected to a reference capacitor which is charged to 1V initially (Vr node). The bottom plate of C2 and C4 is connected to GND. There is also an input switch used to sample a voltage onto the top plates of each capacitor.

**Step 1 - Sampling:**

[image: GRdoe.png]

The input switch is closed and the top plates (positive plate) of the capacitors now move with the input voltage (let's say some sinusoid)

**Step 2 - Stop Sampling:**

[image]

We now open the input switch and a voltage (some voltage of the sinusoid) is sampled on the top plates of each capacitor. Let's call this voltage Vin.

**Step 3 - Switching:**

Here come's the tricky part. Let us now switch the bottom plate of capacitor C2 from GND to Vr.
[image]

The question is: **What is the voltage drop on the reference capacitor?**

**My Solution**

I analyse in two states - the first is after the input voltage Vin has been sampled and the input switch is open. The second is after the capcaitor C2 has been switched from GND to Vref. I calculate the charge in each of these cases and then equate the two, using the law of conservation of charge.

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

Before I equate the two cases, I need to find a relationship between Va,new and Vr,new to ensure I have one equation and one unknown (C123 is parallel combination of C1, C2, C3):
[image]

Finally, I now equate the two cases together:
[image]

Let's do some more algebra:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Finally, I have the equation that tells me the new reference voltage. Let's try a Cref value of 1pF and a C value of 32fF with an initial reference voltage Vr of 1V:

**This gives me a new reference voltage value of 1.094117647V** **How is it possible that the refernece voltage went up?**

Comment: Is this a homework question or do you need to analyze a real circuit? I ask due to the absence of any resistances in your circuit

Comment: @KenGrimes It's not a homework question but you can consider it to be one. I'd just like to understand the charge moving here.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following circuit. Assume there is \$1 \mathrm{V}\$ on each
of the capacitors to start with.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiEtyE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What happens when I press the button? The capacitors get shorted
together. Thus the voltages across them must be equal.

Now when I said each capacitor has \$1\mathrm{V}\$ at the start, I meant
the voltage measured from the + terminal to the - terminal of each
capacitor. But for the voltages across the connected capacitors to be
equal, the voltages have to be measured across the same pair of
nodes. That means from + to - for one capacitor but from - to plus for
the other. You missed this point in your calculations.

But what is the voltage across the capacitors when the button is
pressed? By symmetry, it has to be \$0 \mathrm{V}\$.

Let's try using the conservation of charge. Let the final voltage be
\$V_x\$. Then

$$
C_1 V_x + C_2 \left(-V_x\right) = C_1 \cdot 1 \mathrm{V} + C_2 \cdot 1
\mathrm{V}
$$

Now since \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ are equal, the equation cannot hold for
any \$V_x\$. Where's the problem?

According to Wikipedia, "In physics, charge conservation is the
principle that the total electric charge in an isolated system never
changes." If we take this circuit as our closed system, the total charge
will be (ignoring stray capacitance) the charges on both plates of both
\$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$. A capacitor stores opposite charges on its plates. What
charge conservation gives us is in fact:

$$
\underbrace{C_1 V_x}_{\text{one plate of one capacitor}} +
\underbrace{C_1 \left(-V_x\right)}_{\text{the other plate of one
capacitor}} +
\underbrace{C_2 \left(-V_x\right)}_{\text{one plate of the other
capacitor}} +
\underbrace{C_2 V_x}_{\text{the other plate of the other capacitor}} =
\underbrace{C_1 \left(1\mathrm V\right)}_{\text{one plate of one
capacitor}} +
\underbrace{C_1 \left(-1 \mathrm V\right)}_{\text{the other plate of one
capacitor}} +
\underbrace{C_2 \left(1 \mathrm V\right)}_{\text{one plate of the other
capacitor}} +
\underbrace{C_2 \left(-1 \mathrm V\right)}_{\text{the other plate of the
other capacitor}}
$$

The problem with the way I used charge conservation at first, and also
the way you used it, was that we took only one plate of each capacitor
as the system. These systems are not closed. They are connected by wires
to the other halves of the capacitors on which charge can
flow. Conservation of charge does not apply to systems that are not
closed.

What do we do now? We can take a node, which is some wires that are
connected directly, as our system. It is an open system. Its total
charge is conserved not because no charge can flow across its boundary,
but because even little charge accumulated in it will repel more charge
from getting in. How strong this effect is is measured by stray
capacitance, which is outside the scope of this post. Again, Wikipedia
says:

> This law is also called Kirchhoff's first law, Kirchhoff's point rule,
>   or Kirchhoff's junction rule (or nodal rule).
>
> The principle of conservation of electric charge, combined with the very
>   large repulsive Coulomb forces that will occur if charge "piles up"
>   anywhere, imply that:
>
> > At any node (junction) in an electrical circuit, the sum of currents
> >     flowing into that node is equal to the sum of currents flowing out
> >     of that node
>
> or equivalently
>
> > The algebraic sum of currents in a network of conductors meeting at
> >     a point is zero.

Let \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$ be the voltages at nodes 1 and 2 after the
switch is switched. Their voltages before the switch is switched are
\$V_\mathrm{ref}\$ and \$V_\mathrm{in}\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWxmOz.png)</sup>

The net charge that flows out of node 1 has to be \$0\$, so we have:

$$
\left(C_1 + C_3\right) \left[\left(V_1-V_2\right) -
  \left(V_\mathrm{ref}-V_\mathrm{in}\right)\right] +
C_2 \left[\left(V_1-V_2\right) - \left(-V_\mathrm{in}\right)\right] +
C_5 \left(V_1-V_\mathrm{ref}\right) = 0
$$

The net charge that flows in to node ground has to be 0, so we have:

$$
C_4 \left(V_2 - V_\mathrm{in}\right) +
C_5 \left(V_1 - V_\mathrm{ref}\right) = 0
$$

You can also do the same to node 2. The result will be the first
equation subtract the second, so it will be redundant.

Solve these equations, and you get:

$$
V_1 = \frac{C_1 + C_3 + C_4 \parallel C_5 + \frac{C_5}{C_4 + C_5} C_2}
{C_1 + C_3 + C_4 \parallel C_5 +  C_2} V_\mathrm{ref}
$$

You can see that it will always be less than \$V_\mathrm{ref}\$, and
that it gets closer to \$V_\mathrm{in}\$ as \$C_5\$ gets larger. Your
intuition is correct.

If you prefer working with one unknown instead of two, you can change
node 2 to ground.

Comment: My apologies. I should have been more clear. The positive plates of all capacitors are connected together at that central common node.

Comment: The central, common nodes are all the positive plates of the capacitor.

Comment: That should affect the answer I believe?